# Align SVG with paragraph in Hugo Theme

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an SVG of instagram icon with some text in a paragraph on my footer. This footer is part of the spaced-blog Hugo theme.

I want the svg to align with the text in the paragraph and have some left padding. Please could you tell me a way to do this? I have tried CSS on span containing the svg but it doesn't move the svg. Code below:

```
<footer class="footer p-2">
  <p class="m-b-s">{{ .Site.Title }}&nbsp;&copy {{ now.Format "2006"}}</p>
  <a href="">
    {{ partial "icons/instagram-logo.svg" . }}
  </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why would you vote to close this question? Somebody asks how to add left margin/padding to an SVG and correctly tagged it as a CSS question. Perfectly fine question if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<footer class="footer p-2">
  <p class="m-b-s">{{ .Site.Title }}&nbsp;&copy {{ now.Format "2006"}}</p>
  <a href="" style="display: block; padding-left: 20px;">
    {{ partial "icons/instagram-logo.svg" . }}
  </a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align icon with paragraph, it'll be enough to move `</p>` after `</a>`.

```html
<footer class="footer p-2">
  <p class="m-b-s">{{ .Site.Title }}&nbsp;&copy {{ now.Format "2006"}}
    <a href="">
      {{ partial "icons/instagram-logo.svg" . }}
    </a>
  </p>
</footer>
```